# Shell Script to check the folder created date against the current date/time

Tags: linux

I am preparing shell script if folder created date is equal to the current date/time then it need to call the another script .

My requirement is script need to check only the folder created date against the current date/time not to the files date/time inside the folder .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which shell are you using, and have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Hi icedwater i am working on the shell script and i will post the script here once i completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the **stat** command and the change time of the folder. The change time gives the last date when the metadata of the folder was changed. ([stackexchange link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/what-is-the-difference-between-modify-and-change-in-stat-command-context)). Timestamps of permission changes are also included in this timestamp. This is maybe not exactly what you need.

For the current time, you can use the **date** command. You can compare timestamps between the stat and the date command if you print the output in seconds since the epoch.

- stat --format="%Z" /path/to/folder
- date +%s

Comment: Thank you for your reply Peter i will check and get back to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Suppose TestToday is your Directory Name

*Please replace TestToday with your directory name in below script

Test.sh

```
ls -lrt | grep ^d | grep TestToday |   grep "`date +%b`" | awk -v var="`date +%d | bc`" '$7==var {print $NF}' > DIR_NAME

DIR_EXISTS=`cat DIR_NAME`

#echo $DIR_EXISTS

if [ "$DIR_EXISTS" == "TestToday" ];then

        echo "Calling Shell Script Here."

else

        echo "Directed not created or updated today."

fi
```